# Checking if a user entered integer contains all 1's or 0's?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've tried to convert it to a string and test the string, but can't seem to find the right way to check it and re-prompt the user if they enter something other than a 1 or 0.

```
int binNum, decNum = 0, i = 0, remainderAmount;
string testString;

cout << "Enter a binary number: ";
cin >> binNum;
testString = to_string(binNum);
for (int i = 0; i < testString.length(); i++)
{
    while (testString[i] != 1 && testString[i] != 0)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid binary number: ";
        cin >> binNum;
        testString = to_string(binNum);
    }
}

cout << "Binary number: " << binNum << " is ";

while (binNum != 0)
{
    // Check if remainder is 0 or 1
    remainderAmount = binNum % 10;
    // Remove the last digit from the binary number
    binNum /= 10;
    // Get first decimal number
    decNum += remainderAmount*pow(2,i);
    // Increment the place for the binary power i
    i++;
}

cout << decNum << " in decimal" << endl;
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Read it into a string as text. If it’s not valid, repeat. If it’s valid, convert it to an integer.

Comment: Character inputs evaluate to `'0'` or `'1'` not to `0` or `1`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau 0 is a NUL character, which is still a `char` once cast. That's obviously not the intent here, but the reason why the compiler even compiles this.

Comment: In addition, your nested loop won't work as intended if you ask a second number to the user as you will only check characters after the position an incorrect character was found. So if you enter 112 then 23411, it will think that last number is good

Comment: Learning how to use a debugger might be a good idea too.

Comment: You know that you could just check after `remainderAmount = binNum % 10;` if `remainderAmount` is different then 0 or 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testString[i]` is a `char`, not an `int`.

`0` and `1` are `int`s.

`'0'` and `'1'` are `char`s.

Integer `0` is not the same as character `'0'` (hex 0x30, decimal 48).

Integer `1` is not the same as character `'1'` (hex 0x31, decimal 49).

That is why your `while` is not working correctly.

Also, each time you prompt the user for a new input string, you are not re-testing that string from its beginning. You are picking up at the same index where the previously bad input left off. You need to re-test the full input each time you prompt the user.

Try something more like this:

```
bool isValid(int num) {
    string testString = to_string(num);
    for (int i = 0; i < testString.length(); i++) {
        if (testString[i] != '1' && testString[i] != '0')
            return false;
    }
    return true;

    /* alternatively:
    return (to_string(num).find_first_not_of("01") == string::npos);
    */
}

...

cout << "Enter a binary number: ";
do {
    if (cin >> binNum) {
        if (isValid(binNum)) {
            break;
        }
    } else {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');    
    }
    cout << "Please enter a valid binary number: ";
}
while (true);
```

Comment: Understood, however, is there a different way to write the nested while loop? Whenever I re-enter a valid binary number, it still shows it's invalid.

Comment: @AutumnSail I have rewritten it

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
int binNum, decNum = 0, i = 0, remainderAmount;
bool error = false;

int n;

cout << "Enter a binary number: ";  

do
{

    cin >> binNum;

    n = binNum;
    error = false;
    i = 0;
    decNum = 0;

    while (binNum != 0)
    {

        // Check if remainder is 0 or 1
        remainderAmount = binNum % 10;

        if(remainderAmount & -2)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a valid binary number: ";

            error = true;
            break;
        }

        // Remove the last digit from the binary number
        binNum /= 10;
        // Get first decimal number
        decNum += remainderAmount*pow(2,i);
        // Increment the place for the binary power i
        i++;
    }

}
while(error);

cout << "Binary number: " << n << " is ";

cout << decNum << " in decimal" << endl;
cout << endl;
```